# xml.dom.minidom.parse() in Jython gives an error for XML files with <?xml... and <!DOCTYPE tags

Tags: jython, minidom

It works fine as long as the XML files don't have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and the DOCTYPE tags. I would switch to xml.etree but I already wrote quite a lot of code using minidom. The same thing works in Python.

It sounds like a bug in Jython's minidom, but is there a way to work around it?